# Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of order $n$. Suppose that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B)$ and $A^2B=A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I am having difficulty trying to solve this problem during my practice:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of order $n$. Suppose that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B)$ and $A^2B=A$. Prove the following:
>
> 1. $ B $ and $ A^2 $ have the same nullspace
> 2. $ B^2A = B $

I am given the following hints:

> For 1)
>
> Use the fact that:
>
> (i)  $\mathrm{rank}(AB) \le \min\{\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B)\}, A = (a_{ij})_{m \times n} $ and $ B = (b_{ij})_{n \times p} $ 
> (ii) $\mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{nullity}(A) = n$
>
> to get a relation in $\mathrm{nullity}(B)$ and $\mathrm{nullity}(A^2)$. Then use the fact if $ U \subseteq V $ are vector spaces such that $\dim(U) = \dim(V) $, then $ U = V $.
>
> For 2)
>
> (i) Note that $ Bu = 0 \iff A^2u = 0 $ 
> (ii) Prove that $(B^2A - B)x = 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $

For 1), my attempt:

$$ A^2B = A $$
$$ A^2Bx = 0 \iff Ax = 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n $$
$$ Bx \in \mathrm{nullity}(A^2) $$

I am stuck here. My direction of thought seems wrong. But I really do not know what else to do.

For 2), my attempt:

$$ A^2x = 0, x \in \mathrm{nullity}(A^2), \mathrm{nullity}(B) $$
$$ Bx = 0, x \in \mathrm{nullity}(B), \mathrm{nullity}(A^2) $$
$$ B^2A = BBA = Bu \ \text{(Let }BA = u)$$
$$ \therefore Bu = 0 $$
$$ A^2u = 0 $$
$$ Bu - A^2u = 0 $$
$$ (B - A^2)u = 0 $$

I cannot seem how to get to my desired answer from here.

I spent hours trying to utilize the hints but to no avail. The final product of the proof seems too far from the given conditions. Could someone please advise me?

Answer (score 0):

$\triangleright$ The relation $\mathrm{A}^2 \mathrm{B}=\mathrm{A}$ implies $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{B})\subset \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A})$. Since $\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{B})$, the rank formula applied to $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ gives $\dim(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}))=\dim(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{B}))$ and thus $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{B})$.

$\triangleright$ As $\mathrm{A}^2 \mathrm{B}=\mathrm{A}$, we have $\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A})\subset \mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A}^2)$. Universally, $\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A}^2)\subset \mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A})$, resulting in $\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{A}^2)$ and thus $\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{A}^2)$. Applying the rank formula to $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{A}^2$ gives $\dim(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}))=\dim(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}^2))$. The universal inclusion $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A})\subset \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}^2)$ and the equality of dimensions result in $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}^2)$.

Thus, we have $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A})=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{B})=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}^2)$.

We have:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{A}^2\mathrm{B}=\mathrm{A}
& \quad \text{yields $\quad \mathrm{A}^2\mathrm{B}\mathrm{A}=\mathrm{A}^2$}\\
& \quad \text{yields $\quad \mathrm{A}^2(\mathrm{B}\mathrm{A}-I_n)=0$}\\
& \quad \text{yields $\quad \mathrm{im}(\mathrm{B}\mathrm{A}-I_n)\subset\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{A}^2)$}\\
& \quad \text{yields $\quad \mathrm{im}(\mathrm{B}\mathrm{A}-I_n)\subset\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{B})$}\\
\mathrm{A}^2\mathrm{B}=\mathrm{A}
& \quad \text{yields $\quad \mathrm{B}^2\mathrm{A}=\mathrm{B}$.}
\end{align*}

Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

**A hint for 1):**

Observe a) $\dim\ker A=\dim\ker B$ by the *rank-nullity theorem*.

b) Since $A^2B=A$, we have $\ker B\subseteq \ker A$. Further, $\ker A\subseteq\ker A^2$, so $\ker B\subseteq\ker A^2$, and they have the same dimension…

Comment: Why does $ ker B \subseteq ker A $ if $ A^2B = A $?

Comment: Take any element in $\ker B$ . What's its image by $A^2B$?

Comment: I am not sure. If $ A^2B = A $, that means that both $ A^2B $ and $ A $ have the same column space. But I don't quite get what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: I think in terms of linear maps between vector spaces. However I see I'm missing an argument, I'll complete my answer in a moment.

Comment: You didn't show that $\ker B$ and $\ker A^2$ have the same dimension.